# See more errors details rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4

How can see more detailed errors in my rails app when I'm developing.
Right now I just get this:

[image]

I know that is possible to activate something to see the errors in more detail, but I don't know how to do it.

Any help?

**Edit1:**

In my `development.rb` file I have this:

```
  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
```

**Edit2:**

[image]

Comment: you probably started your app in the production environment, make sure you're running in development environment

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady how can check if I'm in the production environment?

Comment: if you started the app from the console it would say what environment it started in as a start message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you `development.rb` to ensure that:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

Comment: Thanks @dgilperez !
I already have done this. I edited the question, with the details from my development.rb file.

Comment: And did you restart your server and you keep seeing those 500 errors?

Comment: Yes I did. I really don't know what's happening!